# Trying to implement weekly DateRangePicker control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application project, and I want to add a textbox to a view to hold a 7-day range. The textbox will have two icons, one on the left side and another on the right side of the textbox. When a user clicks the icon on the left, the textbox will update to show the previous 7-day period; when the user clicks the next 7-day range, the textbox will update to show the next 7-day period. The ideal format of the 7-day range is "8/14/2016 - 8/20/2016". I ended up refactoring a solution originally written for “jQuery v1.6.2”; the app I’m building is running on “jQuery v2.2.3”. I’ve replaced all of the v1.6.2 features that have been deprecated. The outdated code from which my solution is based can be found at “http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.com/2011/07/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker.html”. My code is currently set up to display the weekly date range in a couple of span tags; however, I prefer to display the weekly date range in the text box from which the datepicker is launched. My code is listed below; I’ve commented it to identify areas where I’m getting values and areas where I’m not:

```
    $(function () {

        var startDate;
        var endDate;

        var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('.ui-weekpicker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-default');
            }, 1);
        }

        var setDates = function (input) {
            debugger;
            var $input = $(input);
            var date = $input.datepicker('getDate');//Set to date value selected in jQuery datepicker
            var loIsDate = new Date(date);//loIsDate has a value, but its "_proto" property is set to "Invalid Date"

            if (date != 'Invalid Date') {
                var firstDay = $input.datepicker("option", "firstDay");
                var dayAdjustment = loIsDate.getDay() - firstDay;//Set to valid constant value
                if (dayAdjustment < 0) {
                    dayAdjustment += 7;
                }
                startDate = new Date(loIsDate.getFullYear(), loIsDate.getMonth, loIsDate.getDate() - dayAdjustment);//set to "Invalid Date'
                endDate = new Date(loIsDate.getFullYear(), loIsDate.getMonth(), loIsDate.getDate() - dayAdjustment + 6);//set to valid date

                var dateFormat = $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                });

                $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate));
                $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate));
            }
        }

        $('.week-picker').datepicker({
            beforeShow: function () {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('ui-weekpicker');
                selectCurrentWeek();
            },
            onClose: function () {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('ui-weekpicker');
            },
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                setDates(this);
                selectCurrentWeek();
                $(this).change();
            },
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var cssClass = '';
                if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                    cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
                return [true, cssClass];
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                selectCurrentWeek();
            }
        });

        setDates('.week-picker');

        $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mousemove', function () {
            $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
        });

        $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        });

    });

<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:0.5em;">
                        <span>Time Period:</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="image" src="~/Images/arrow-l.gif" alt="Previous Week" style="margin-top: 0.5em;" title="Previous Week" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="timePeriodTextBox" type="text" class="form-control week-picker" style="width:8em;" />
                        <span id="startDate"></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="image" src="~/Images/arrow-r.gif" alt="Next Week" style="margin-top: 0.5em;" title="Next Week" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I run the program and click the box attached to the jQuery datepicker, the datepicker does appear and I'm able to select a date. After selecting a date, a date in the format "8/19/2016" appears in the textbox but the weekly date range is not displayed in the two span tags.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Persistence pays off. I was able to solve my problem. My solution is listed below:

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#weekRangeTextBox').val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings)
                 + ' - ' + $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('#nextWeekButton, #previousWeekButton').on('click', function (e) {
        var date = $('.week-picker').datepicker('getDate');
        e.target.id == 'nextWeekButton' ? date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7) : date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        $('#weekRangeTextBox').val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", startDate)
                 + ' - ' + $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", endDate));
    });
});
```